# How to create website in Apache 2 Debian 8?

Tags: debian, configuration, apache-httpd

I have configured Apache2 in Debian 8 and created a website. I created a new .conf file in `/etc/apache2/site-avaliable` directory. I edited the file properly to point to the directory which holds the .html file.

My question is when I enter my url I get a page with has my .html file as a link and I have to click on it to view the page. The url after I enter the link is:

```
www.mysite.com/file1.html
```

How can I go directly to file1.html when I enter mysite.com with no link?

Thanks

Comment: @Jeff Schaller can you please assist me with this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`httpd` has a list of files to try to display when you give a URL that points to a directory, which can be configured with the [DirectoryIndex directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex). (Its default value is just index.html, so if you renamed your file1.html to index.html, it would also show immediately.)

The listing that you see is generated by [mod_autoindex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html); but if you disable it and don't have an index.html (or similar), you'd just get a permission denied error page instead.